# About unique zero of a polynomial of degree $4$: where is this theorem coming from?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

Looking at the first comment of DavidP in the question

[How to understand for which $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ the equation $a-x+\frac{b}{x^3}=0$ has a unique zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367243/how-to-understand-for-which-a-b-in-mathbbr-the-equation-a-x-fracbx3?noredirect=1#comment9123695_4367243)

I am wondering what you can tell that the only way a 4th degree polynomial will have a unique zero is if $f^{\prime}(c)=0$ and $f(c)=0$ is simultaneously true only once, and the functions outputs have constant sign aside from the zeros.

I would say it comes from the intermediate value theorem, but I am not sure about that.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By the premise of the problem, the quartic has a real root $f(c)=0$. Assume WLOG that the leading coefficient is positive, then the quartic will always have a global minimum at $f'(c')=0$. If $c' \ne c$ then the minimum must be negative, so there must exist at least one other real root besides $c$. The only way for that to not happen is $c'=c$.

Comment: Why you say that “ so there must exist at least one other real root besides c”?

Comment: The minimum being negative means the polynomial changes sign on both $(-\infty, c')$ and $(c',+\infty)$ so it must have (at least) one real root in each interval. At most one of those can be $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, a polynomial $f(x)$ of even degree with a positive leading coefficient has a unique real root iff $\,f(x) \ge 0$ on $\mathbb R\,$, and there exists a unique $\,c \in \mathbb R\,$ such that $\,f(c)=f'(c)=0\,$.

- The $\,\implies\,$ part: let the unique root be $\,c\,$, then $\,f(x) \gt 0\,$ for all $\,x \ne c\,$, so $\,c\,$ is a (global) minimum and therefore $\,f'(c)=0\,$. By uniqueness of the root, there can exist no other $\,c'\,$ where $\,f(c')=0\,$, so $\,c\,$ is the unique point with $\,f(c)=f'(c)=0\,$,
- The $\,\impliedby\,$ part: suppose another real root exists $\,c' \ne c\,$, then $\,f'(c') \ne 0\,$ by uniqueness of the multiple root, and therefore $\,f(x)\,$ changes sign at $\,x=c'\,$, which contradicts $\,f(x) \ge 0\,$.